# How to convert const unsigned short to unsigned short?

Tags: c++

So far I have tried this but I am still getting an error in the code below:

```
#include<iostream>
typedef unsigned short unichar;
typedef const unichar unimap_t[2];
unimap_t x = {0x0004,0x00ff}; 

const unimap_t * ret()
{

    return x;
}
int main()
{
    unsigned short* pX2 = const_cast < unsigned short* > (ret());
    std::cout <<pX2[1]; 
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error.

```
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
sa.cpp:22:60: error: invalid const_cast from type ‘const unichar (*)[2] 
    {aka const short unsigned int (*)[2]}’ to type ‘short unsigned int*’`
```

Comment: Why is this down voted? The question is clear, poster shows the code. And it is an anwserable question with a practical programming question.

Comment: @hetepeperfan: Actually, the question is not clear. The title asks how to do one thing (convert a `const unsigned short` to an `unsigned short`), but in the code he is attempting to do something quite different (`convert a const unsigned short (*)[2]` to an `unsigned short*`).  That's not to say it deserves a downvote, it's an honest mistake, but it definitely needs some clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `ret()` function to return a pointer to `x`:

```
const unimap_t *ret()
{
    return &x; 
}
```

and add some reinterpret cast:

```
int main() {
    unsigned short* pX2 = const_cast < unsigned short* >(
            reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short*>(ret()) 
            );  
    std::cout <<pX2[1]; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `unichar const*` for the return type of the function.  If you need `reinterpret_cast`, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Certainly if you use `reinterpret_cast` to get from a pointer-to-array to a pointer-to-its-first-element you're doing something wrong. Dereferencing followed by array-to-pointer decay achieves the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

First, you're not returning a `unsigned short*`, but an
`unsigned short (*)[2]`, a pointer to an array of 2 `unsigned
short`.  This is probably not what you want; the signature of
your function should probably be:

```
unichar const* ret();
```

(C style arrays are fundamentally broken, and represent
a special case in the type system.)  Alternatively, you might
want to return a reference:

```
unimap_t const& ret();
```

This should convert to `unsigned short const*`.